# Web Services error without 'PHP display errors'

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop

When I try to load the manufacturers xml via web services using http://www.mywebsite.com/api/manufacturers

it returns to me:

```
<error>
<message>
<![CDATA[
Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.
]]>
</message>
</error>
```

If I enable display PHP errors it works, the manufacturers are displayed correctly without erros.

I got this problem only win Manufacturers.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try to find error.log of your web server.

Comment: @sectus i opened the file error_log_php and I found the error

`[06-Feb-2015 12:29:15 Europe/Rome] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 24 in /home/lmloggic/public_html/classes/Tools.php on line 1150`

I watched inside the file "Tools.php" but is a set of standard functions

Comment: soooooo, what is on 1150 line?

Comment: @sectus
`// Remove all non-whitelist chars.
if ($allow_accented_chars)
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\'\:\/\[\]-\pL]/u', '', $str);
else
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\'\:\/\[\]-]/','', $str);` **Line 1150 is** `$str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\'\:\/\[\]-\pL]/u', '', $str);`

Comment: Do you mean `\[\]\-\pL` ?

Comment: @sectus it solved, now i can see everything with /api/xxxx?display=[id,name] or with other filters, but if i use /api/xxxx?display=all or /api/xxxx it continues to give me error at line 1150. xxxx is what i want to display (products, categories, ...), I don't need that now, so i can consider it solved, thanks